# To earn the 'Tumbleweed' badge, what counts as 'low views'?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've been searching for my next badge, and I came across the Tumbleweed badge, which has the following requirements to earn:

### ask a question with:

1. a score of 0
2. no answers
3. no comments
4. low views

for a week.

> ***What counts as 'low views'?***

**I'm asking for a quantity.**

Comment: One data point: I got the Tumbleweed badge on a question with 90 views.

Comment: @called2voyage - It's a low number of views in a week that count, not the total. Were it not for your comment (and now mine), this question would have been a good tumbleweed candidate (zero score, no answers, and asked in a very low traffic corner of the SE network).

Comment: @David Hammen - but it also says 'no comments', so this question would not win it. But it's weird that it's a bronze badge, even though it's moderately difficult to earn.

Comment: @Imtherealsanic - It's a door prize, and a consolation one at that. That said, I believe the "no comments" means no comments during the week during which the view number is low rather than no comments ever.

Comment: so you're telling me that if somebody comments _**after**_ the badge is earned, it _won't effect_ you?

Comment: @Imtherealsanic Badges are, generally, never revoked. So yes, a comment, extra views, or score changes won't affect an already awarded badge.

Comment: Tumbleweed no longer exists as a badge.  This question is now obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/350567):

> Ask a question that after its first week of existence has score of 0, no answers, no comments and [**no more than 60 views**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/7357).